# Angular 2 - own component representing input/text always has class ng-untouched

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have my own component talking to FormModule:

```
let nextUniqueId = 0;
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'fgnp-input-text',
    template: '<input 
        class="fgnp-form-text" 
        [id]="id" 
        [value]="value" 
        [name]="name" 
        (input)="change($event)"
        >',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextComponent),
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class InputTextComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() id: string = `fgnp-input-text-${nextUniqueId++}`;
    @Input()
    set value(value: any) {
        if (value !== undefined && value != this._value) {
            this._value = value;
            this.onChangeCallback(this._value);
        }
    }

    get value(): any {
        return this._value;
    };

    change(value: any) {
        this.value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== undefined && value != this._value) {
            this._value = value;
        }
    }

    private _value: string = '';
    private onChangeCallback = (_: any) => { };

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any) { }

}
```

and usage

```
<fgnp-input-text formControlName="MTU"></fgnp-input-text>
```

It renders HTML:

```
<fgnp-input-text formcontrolname="MTU" ng-reflect-name="MTU" 
    class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input class="fgnp-form-text" ng-reflect-disabled="false" 
        ng-reflect-id="fgnp-input-text-0" id="fgnp-input-text-0" 
        ng-reflect-value="2000">
</fgnp-input-text>
```

When I change value to invalid one the element `fgnp-input-text` get classes `ng-untouched ng-dirty ng-invalid`. Why there is a class `ng-untouched` ? When I used native HTML `input` it had class `ng-untouched` at the begining and when I touched the control (i.e. clicked with mouse) the class changed to `ng-touched`. I'd like to copy this behavior to my component.

Answer (score 0):

You should fire registerOnTouched(fn: any) { } as you do with change callback